# Updating a field on multiple Resources in tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have a tastypie ModelResource that I'd like to use to update one field of multiple instances of this Model at once.

```
class Message(models.Model):
    # ... fields etc
    unread = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I have tried to send a PATCH request (in tests, at the moment), but this doesn't work:

```
api = TestApiClient()
data = {'unread': False}
api.patch('/path/to/resource/', data=data)
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a patch request to update a field of several instances, you have to send objects. Like so :

```
data = {objects:[{'unread':False,'resource_uri':'uri/of/your/instance'},{'unread':False,'resource_uri':'uri/of/your/instance'}]}
```

More infos [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html#bulk-operations) and [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#patch-list)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I didn't notice that this had been posted, so apologies for not marking it as the answer sooner.